# Running SelfHosted Web Application with Owin without external access

Tags: c#, web

I have a web application done in razor and i want to convert it to a normal client application. So what i thought of is to self host that web application and serve it through `WebControl` in `WinForms`, i already done this using owin. However the self hosted application can also be accessed through a browser or any external machine if privileges are given. My question here, how to prevent any external browser from accessing my self hosted owin web app, and still connect through the my client's internal browser ?